# What to do about such activity?

Tags: discussion

I found a user who has asked 3 distinct questions on different days and seemed *irrelevant* to the site.

**Note that the questions asked apparently could not be deemed as questions**. Should anything be done to the user or should we wait for the user to "grow"?

**Links to the questions:-**
1. [Setting up a wireless adapter [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1433893/setting-up-a-wireless-adapter)

2. [which editor is best for python coding? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1435532/which-editor-is-best-for-python-coding)
3. [What Makes You unique Today?](https://superuser.com/questions/1438825/what-makes-you-unique-today)

Would it be too rough on the user to take action, or do we ignore such activity or do something like contacting him?

Comment: I spotted the same thing and left a message in the Ask a Moderator chat.  #1 & #2 were closed, but if you read the questions, they are just snippets of computer-related drivel.  They aren't just irrelevant, they're nonsense posts.  #3 is more obvious.  This user is just trolling the site.  I think they escalated #3 to be more obvious because they weren't getting the expected negative reaction.

Comment: Huh, I think I automatically marked #3 as spam, because it looked exactly like the kind of post that always includes a sponsored website link...

Comment: Quite curiously this user has some well-received posts on other network sites. Perhaps they're account got hacked by their cat...who happens to type better than an infinite number of pet monkeys.

Comment: Maybe merged to a different SE network.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Vote to close the posts. Soon enough the low-quality filter will catch up and prevent the user from posting.

Comment: The low-quality filter also needs you help by **voting**. If you see a low-quality post, *please downvote it*!